# Change index in a pandas dataframe and add additional time column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that currently has no specifiy index (thus when printing an automatic index is created which beginns with 0). Now I would like to have a "timeslot" index that beginns with 1 and an additional "time of the day" column in the dataframe. Here you can see a screenshot of how theoutput csv should look like. Can you tell me how to do this?

[image]

Comment: I didn't downvote but please can you update your post with the input dataframe as plain text (just the left dataframe)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `pd.date_range`:

```
df['time of day'] = pd.date_range('1970-1-1', periods=len(df), freq='H') \
                      .strftime('%H:%M')
```

Setup:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 50, (30, 2)), columns=['Column 1', 'Column 2'])
df.insert(0, 'time of day', pd.date_range('1970-1-1', periods=len(df), freq='H').strftime('%H:%M'))
df.index.name = 'timeslot'
df.index += 1
print(df)

# Output:
         time of day  Column 1  Column 2
timeslot                                
1              00:00        43        33
2              01:00        20        11
3              02:00        40        10
4              03:00        19        28
5              04:00        10        27
6              05:00        27        10
7              06:00         1        10
8              07:00        33        36
9              08:00        32         2
10             09:00        23        32
11             10:00         1        17
12             11:00        48        42
13             12:00        21         3
14             13:00        48        28
15             14:00        41        46
16             15:00        48        43
17             16:00        47         6
18             17:00        33        21
19             18:00        38        19
20             19:00        17        40
21             20:00         8        24
22             21:00        28        22
23             22:00         2        13
24             23:00        24         3
25             00:00         4         1
26             01:00         8         9
27             02:00        19        36
28             03:00        30        36
29             04:00        43        39
30             05:00        43         3
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment Corralien. Actually I have 2 remarks: 1) How can I shift the new created dataframe onto the second position (should be the second column) 2) How can I give the first column a name?

Comment: @PeterBe. I updated my answer. Can you check my demo, please? Is it what you expect?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your tremendous help. I upvoted and accepted your answer. Just out of curiosity: Why are you specifying `1970-1-1` as the date and not the current date for example?

Comment: Seems overkill to use datetime just to convert an int to string :p

Comment: @PeterBe. The date doesn't matter because we only keep the time.

Comment: @mozway. If you have more than 24 rows, you have to cycle over hours

Comment: then just use modulo ;) I'll update my answer to demonstrate

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your dataframe is `df`:

```
df['time of day'] = df.index.astype(str).str.rjust(2, '0')+':00'
df.index += 1
```

output: No output as no text input was provided

##### if there are more than 24 rows:

```
df['time of day'] = (df.index%24).astype(str).str.rjust(2, '0')+':00'
df.index += 1
```